# Confusion about HTTP verbs

Tags: rest, http, asp.net-web-api

While building my Web API, I have encountered some cases, where I'm not sure what HTTP verbs to use.

1. **Downloading a file with a side effect**

   My first thought was to use GET, but later I did realize, when a client calls the API to download a file, the server also updates the counter in the DB indicating total number of downloads and the date of the last download.

   Isn't this against the specification? The server state was changed, after all. Shouldn't this be a POST/PUT? But if the POST/PUT would be used, I wouldn't be able to share the link and use it from the browser.
2. **Generating random list of values**

   In my case I need to call the API to generate random list of questions for a test (exam). The request doesn't change anything on the server, it just produces different response content each time the client calls it, so I guess using GET is alright. The indempotency applies only for the server state, not the result handed to the client, right? So is it allowed to request (GET) the same resource repeatedly with different outcome (as seen from the client)?
3. **Generating list of values based on the user input**

   The last case is similar to the previous. I need the server to generate list of questions. This time based on the previous test's wrong answers. Again, the request doesn't alter server data, but I need to send to the server (relatively) long list of items, which wouldn't have to fit as a query string. That's why I would think a POST with a payload in the body could be used. But to be honest, it feels weird.

Is there a definitive answer which verbs to use for each case?

Comment: For #1, a minimal side affect like logging, I wouldn't consider that "server state changed"

Comment: For #2 you say "is it allowed" but the answer is "of course it's allowed". You can pretty much violate all the "rules" if you want to. They're actually guidelines, not rules. You should be asking if it makes sense, not whether it's allowed or not.

Comment: Well, does it make sense?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.  Read [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) to understand the reasoning why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Downloading a file with a side effect

> My first thought was to use GET

And that's the right answer.  HTTP Methods are about semantics, not implementation.

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What
> it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and
> therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface
> or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that
> causes loss of property -- [Fielding (2002)](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)

## Generating random list of values

> it just produces different response content each time the client calls it, so I guess using GET is alright.

Yup - again, as long as the *semantics* are [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), GET is a fine choice.

## Generating list of values based on the user input

> I need to send to the server (relatively) long list of items, which wouldn't have to fit as a query string. That's why I would think a POST with a payload in the body could be used. But to be honest, it feels weird.

So if you weren't worried about length of the identifier, GET would be the usual answer here, with all of the user input encoded into the URI.

At this point, you have a couple of options.

The simplest one is to simply use POST, with the user input in the message body, and the resulting list of values in the Response.  That shouldn't feel weird -- `POST` is the method in HTTP with the fewest semantic constraints.

Alternatively, you can rethink your protocol such that the client is creating a "query resource", using the message body as the payload.  So POST could work here again, or alternatively you could use PUT (with a somewhat different handling of the URI).

A third possibility is to look in the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol Method Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) to see if there is an extension method with the semantics that you need, paying careful attention to whether or not the method is safe.  SEARCH and REPORT might fit your needs.

> If I decide later, I want to record each generated test to the DB, would you recommend to change the API to POST or keep it as it is? In case of changing the HTTP verb, the client wouldn't notice any functional change, but it would break the API, so semantics-wise, wouldn't it be more appropriate to use POST right from the start, after all? In both cases the meaning would be "create a new test".

No, but change things up a bit and things get interesting.  The interesting bit isn't really "record to the database", but "be able to pull it out of the database later".  When you start looking toward creating a new resource that can be retrieved later, `GET` stops being a good fit.

> it would break the API

Only because you are ignoring an important REST constraint - [REST api are hypertext driven](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).  On the web, we can easily change from GET to POST by changing from a link to a form (or from a GET form to a POST form).  The client isn't playing "guess the URI" or "guess the method" because the representation of state includes these details.

But yes, if you make a big enough change to the semantics, it's not going to be backwards compatible.  So don't try to pretend that it is backwards compatible - just create a new protocol using new resources.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Regarding #2, you said it is about semantics. So let's say for now I use GET. If I decide later, I want to record each generated test to the DB, would you recommend to change the API to POST or keep it as it is? In case of changing the HTTP verb, the client wouldn't notice any functional change, but it would break the API, so semantics-wise, wouldn't it be more appropriate to use POST right from the start, after all? In both cases the meaning would be "create a new test".

Comment: Thank you for the update! "Only because you are ignoring an important REST constraint - REST api are hypertext driven.". Yes, I do realize it. At the moment I'm not sure if I'm ready for a real REST API. For now I probably settle down with a "REST-like wanna be".